# How to write the JEST Unit test for the require('passport-openidconnect').Strategy node module

Tags: jestjs, passport.js

I am having the file with OIDC implementation like below.

```
const passport = require('passport');
const passportOidc = require('passport-openidconnect').Strategy;

module.exports.oktaOidcVerify = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      
        const oidcStrategy = new passportOidc(
            oidcOptions,
            async (
                issuer,
                profile,
                context,
                idToken,
                accessToken,
                refreshToken,
                done
            ) => {
                try {
                    if (!profile.id) {
                        return done(
                            new Error('Profile not found'),
                            null
                        );
                    } else {
                        return done(null, profile, {
                            accessToken,
                            refreshToken
                        });
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                }
            }
        );

        passport.use('oidc', oidcStrategy);

        passport.serializeUser((user, next) => {
            next(null, user);
        });

        passport.deserializeUser((obj, next) => {
            next(null, obj);
        });

        next();
    } catch (error) {
    }
};
```

In my express server.js file, I am adding as the middleware like below

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(oktaOidcVerify);
```

Is there a way to write JEST Unit Test case for only the "oktaOidcVerify" function by passing the sample request?